# settings launcher in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Hi I am trying to launch the app settings page from my application. 
i am using following code mentioned in msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394011%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

```
ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

but i can get the ConnectionSettings class reference in my code.
i have included

```
 using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```

in my code but its not available there. Even checked the Microsoft.Phone.Tasks namespace there is no ConnectionSettingsTask  available..

I am confused , if its documented at msdn why its not available in sdk. By the way i am using  7.1 sdk.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you try creating a new application for 7.1 and using the code. Does it still show the same error? You might have created the project for 7 instead of 7.1, just a possibility.

Comment: I have created the project for 7.1 , infact testing on device...

Comment: Did the new application give you the same error?

Comment: Alright, how about other launchers? Are they working? Try `EmailComposeTask` or `PhoneCallTask`. Also, if you could dump the `WMAppManifest.xml` it would give us something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Update your application to version 7.1 or more..
There you will find.